# Updating my ear dependencies to match modules of new Wildfly version

Tags: wildfly

We have an ear deployed in Wildfly. We are updating the version of Wildfly to the latest. Wildfly has lots of jars in its modules directory, for example, apache commons-collections. Some of these jars are also in our ear/lib. Do I have to change the versions of the jars in our ear to match the versions of the same jars in the Wildfly modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not need to upgrade any dependencies you provide in your EAR. That said you should make sure you're not providing any Jakarta EE/Java EE dependencies that are provided by WildFly in your EAR.